# TypeError: 'int' object not callable Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

New to programming here, been trying to write a simple code to implement the 1D Golden Search Method to find a minimizer for a function. Can't seem to find what I'm doing to cause this TypeError

```
import math
def function(float):
  fx = 8*(exp(1-float))+7(log1p(float))
  return fx

while (xmax-xmin) > u:
  if function(x1) < function(x2):
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-a126a69b14a7> in <module>()

---> 12   if function(x1) < function(x2):


<ipython-input-37-a126a69b14a7> in function(float)
      1 import math
      2 def function(float):
----> 3   fx = 8*(exp(1-float))+7(log1p(float))


TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: You need a `*` after the `7` to multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```py
def function(val):
  fx = 8*(math.exp(1-val))+7*(math.log(val)) # added * between 7 and parenthesis
  return fx
```

Also, it's bad practice to use builtin names for variables, so `float` has been changed

Edit:
Per @tobiask's comment, you will need `exp` to be called like `math.exp` and `log` will need `math.log` unless `log1p` is being defined elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `*` after the 7 in the second part of your expression. Therefore python understands you are trying to call the `int 7` as if it were a callable (for example a function as it is `print("hello")`).

It should be `8*(exp(1-float))+7*(log1p(float))`.

Hope it helps!